# EE 2.8.1 relationships change

Tags: relationships, conditionals

I had

```
{parents channel="gallery"}
    {if parents:no_results}Galleries: 0</a>{/if}
    {if count >= 1}
        {if count == total_results}
        Galleries: <a href="{site_url}models/profile/{embed:modelid}">{parents:total_results}</a>
        {/if}
    {/if}
{/parents}
```

And if 3 galleries and 2 videos, it would say  Galleries 3 Videos 2

Now it says Galleries 3 Galleries 3 Galleries 3 Videos 2 Videos 2

I'm sure EE's realtionships changed...any idea what I need to change it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must prefix *all* of the variables inside of a `parents` tag with `parents:`,including  `count` and `total_results`.

You also have an extra conditional which you don't need - and, note the change in creating the link to use the `{path}` variable.

```
{parents channel="gallery"}
    {if parents:no_results}Galleries: 0{/if}
    {if parents:count == parents:total_results}
        Galleries: <a href="{path="models/profile/{embed:modelid}"}">{parents:total_results}</a>
    {/if}
{/parents}
```

Comment: Btw, how come I dont have to use the field="something" tag in the first line?

Comment: Ah - well you *should* use the `field` parameter, but if you don't I think it will just grab all relationships for that entry (from all fields)?